# Projectivization of the tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I want to explicitly write down equations for a variety in 
$$\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^2}\oplus T_{\mathbb{P}^2})$$
What would be the natural way to do this? I know how the equations should look like over each point of $\mathbb{P}^2$ but it doesn't seem trivial to me how to "translate" them into global equations.

Comment: Just write the local equations canonically, this will give their global version.

Comment: Perhaps you should give us more details...

Comment: I find your question not clear at all...

Comment: I want to construct a surface 
$$S\subset\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{P}^2})\mapsto\mathbb{P}^2$$ such that the the generic fiber over of $S\mapsto \mathbb{P}^2$ consists of six points. So locally this is just the intersection of a twisted cubic and a quadric in the relative P3 and my question is just how explicitly can I write those equations? I was told that there might be a toric construction of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{P}^2})$ that I can adapt but I'm not sure how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A twisted cubic on $P^3$ can be realized as the degeneration locus of a map $A\otimes O(-1) \to B\otimes O$, where $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces of dimension 2 and 3. In a relative situation you should replace vector spaces by vector bundles on the base. So, choose a pair of a vector bundles $A$ and $B$ on $P^2$ of rank 2 and three, and a map $p^*A\otimes O(-1) \to p^*B$, where $p:P_{P^2}(T \oplus T) \to P^2$ is the projection and $O(-1)$ is the relative $O(-1)$ for $p$. Note that such map is given by a morphism of vector bundles
$A\otimes(T \oplus T) \to B$ on $P^2$.

Further, a relative quadric is given by a section of a vector bundle $p^*L\otimes O(2)$, where $L$ is a line bundle on $P^2$. Such section is given by a section of a vector bundle $L\otimes S^2T^*$ on $P^2$.

Altogether, you obtain the equations of your (generically) sixfold covering.